# Creating a biological database: First steps?

Tags: database, database-design

My lab is doing a lot of sequencing, but the way the sequences are documented makes it difficult to retrieve them or keep track of the data. I would like to create a database that has following features:
-A Graphical user interface to allow one to upload/retrieve/view data, and can incorporate links to quickly BLAST or analyse the sequences with other online tools.
-allows one to access it in the command line
-that has another section on the GUI that has records of what's in the lab, what needs to be ordered etc.

I wanted to know if there are general database templates I can adopt and modify to suit my lab needs? I have no experience in database design but have read about mySQL.

What are the first steps I should take in embarking on this project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question and problem domain (one I now have expierence with btw).  Your first step is to decide on a general architecture and then select technologies for this.

For the web/graphical side, there are lots of off the shelf components (I assume you are aware of tools like AntiSMASH, JBrowse, etc).  But you will need to evaluate these.  That is way outside the scope of the db side however.

On the database side, PostgreSQL performs admirably here.  I have worked on a heavily loaded 10+TB db which was specifically storing sequencing data, BLAST reports, and so forth.  If you add stuff like PostBIS on top of that, you get something quite functional.

A lot of the heavier portions of the industry however are using Hadoop because of the fact that the quantity of data available is increasing very rapidly but the amount of expertise required to make that work is also appropriately higher.